# Using conditional for displaying special content to specific entry

Tags: channel-entries, conditionals, loop

Trying to display different link for one entry (`thing1`) inside channel entries loop.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel=“things”}

     <h2>{title}</h2>
     <p>{description}</p>

     {if url_title == ’thing1’}
     <a href=“somecustomlink.html”>Read more</a>
     {if:else}
     <a href=“{path=’things’}/{url_title}”>Read more</a>
     {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Problem is, that EE uses to compare `{url_title}` with current template, not with “things” channel entrie's.

How to write this conditional?

Comment: Is this `exp:channel:entries` variable pair nested inside another one?

Answer (score 0):

If this exp:channel:entries code block is appearing on a page that is used for displaying a specific entry (e.g. a specific news article page) then try adding a dynamic="no" parameter to the channel:entries tag. Otherwise, I would double-check that Robson hasn't already hit the nail on the head with his 'nested channel:entries' hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with using `{title}` instead of `{url_title}` in conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Although not as flexible, I'm adding suggestion to write the conditional using `{if segment_x == 'thing1'}` as another viable option.